# How to fetch OTP From Mail and print on a text field?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail-imap

I'm trying to automate registration on a website but that site send OTP to the email. so I need to fetch the OTP from the mail and print it to text field.

I am using this code but it's not showing unread message count and the OTP verification mail.

Can anyone help with how can I extract OTP from the email and submit it on the website ?

```
                     package MAVEN.GmailIMAP;

                import java.io.BufferedReader;
                import java.io.InputStreamReader;
                import java.util.Properties;

                import javax.mail.Flags;
                import javax.mail.Folder;
                import javax.mail.Message;
                import javax.mail.Session;
                import javax.mail.Store;

                public class Gmail3 {

                    public static void ReceiveMail(String FolderName,String SubjectContent, String emailContent, int lengthOfOTP){


                        String hostName = "imap.gmail.com";//change it according to your mail

                        String username = "test12345@gmail.com";//username 

                        String password = "test12345"; //password

                        int messageCount;

                        int unreadMsgCount;

                        String emailSubject;

                        Message emailMessage;

                        String searchText=null ;

                        Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();

                        sysProps.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

                        try {

                            Session session = Session.getInstance(sysProps, null);

                            Store store = session.getStore();

                            store.connect(hostName, username, password);

                            Folder emailBox = store.getFolder(FolderName);

                            emailBox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

                            messageCount = emailBox.getMessageCount();

                            System.out.println("Total Message Count: " + messageCount);

                            unreadMsgCount = emailBox.getNewMessageCount();

                            System.out.println("Unread Emails count:" + unreadMsgCount);

                            for(int i=messageCount; i>(messageCount-unreadMsgCount); i--)

                            {

                                emailMessage = emailBox.getMessage(i);

                                emailSubject = emailMessage.getSubject();

                                if(emailSubject.contains(SubjectContent))

                                {

                                    System.out.println("OTP mail found");

                                    String line;

                                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(emailMessage.getInputStream()));

                                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                                        buffer.append(line);

                                    }

                                    String messageContent=emailContent;

                                    String result = buffer.toString().substring(buffer.toString().indexOf(messageContent));

                                    searchText = result.substring(messageContent.length(), messageContent.length()+lengthOfOTP);

                                    System.out.println("Text found : "+ searchText);

                                    emailMessage.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);

                                    break;

                                }

                                emailMessage.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);

                            }

                            emailBox.close(true);

                            store.close();


                        } catch (Exception mex) {

                            mex.printStackTrace();

                            System.out.println("OTP Not found ");

                        }

                        return searchText ;

                    }




                    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        ReceiveMail("FolderName","SubjectContent","One Time Password (OTP):",6);

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Email body scanner should work for the input which you are looking for

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class OtpRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        String regex = "((is|otp|password|key|code|CODE|KEY|OTP|PASSWORD|Do).[0-9]{4,8}.(is|otp|password|key|code|CODE|KEY|OTP|PASSWORD)?)|(^[0-9]{4,8}.(is|otp|password|key|code|CODE|KEY|OTP|PASSWORD))";
        String text = "To auth... \n\n869256\n\n Do is your login OTP. Treat this as confidential. Sharing it with anyone gives them full access to your Paytm Wallet. Paytm never calls to verify your OTP.";


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);

        int otp = -1;
        String line = null;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            line = sc.nextLine().trim();
            try{
                otp = Integer.parseInt(line);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfx) {
                //Ignore the exception
            }
        }
        System.out.println(otp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you passed youe email body in placeholderPattern.matcher(emailBody) ? If yes then what text you need to parse ?

Comment: I had tried this method but still it's not working. its not fetching otp from the mail instead showing otp which is stored in the String Text.

[https://imgur.com/HfZHOBS]

Comment: can you pass is|otp|password|key|code|CODE|KEY|OTP|PASSWORD either one these key words along with otp e.g. 694554 is, 694554 code, 694554 key

Comment: yes I have passed the email body but it's still not working.
I need to fetch the OTP from the mail and submit it on the website.

Comment: is your OTP going to be a separate line alone and that line will only have OTP and nothing else ?

Comment: can you pass is|otp|password|key|code|CODE|KEY|OTP|PASSWORD either one these key words along with otp e.g. "694554 is \n\n"

Comment: if I pass that regex then it's the result [ https://imgur.com/G7U4zGI ]

Comment: @Sourav Can you pass "is" along with your OTP ? like  "694554 is \n\n"

Comment: sir Yes I did this. check here sir [ https://imgur.com/IRyyJzD ]

Comment: updated the ans with the input which you were using earlier. It should work for you.